# How to access a desktop based application on a cloud server

Tags: server, desktop-application

I have a small application which is desktop based application, i want to install it on a cloud Windows server so that i can access it anywhere, so i want to know how am i going to access the application when install it on the cloud server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you're using the *right* kind of cloud service. The more common ones allow you to expose services, which don't fit your use case. Instead you should be using a service that provides a *Virtual Desktop*. The instructions for using it will be specific to the cloud provider that you pick.

A quick search of *Desktop Cloud Providers* should yield cloud services that may work for your use case.